# How to calculate the angle of a game object behind the player in a game of snake

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, angle

I am creating a game of Snake in the Unity Engine with a 2d Orthographic camera. I want to detect if a food pellet is behind or in front of the snake at a certain point.

I have tried multiple methods such as this one but I have not been able to figure this out.

```
IEnumerator ChangeFood()
    {
        //waits three seconds then puts all active food instances into a list, then picks a random object from that list and changes it
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        GameObject[] foodList = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Food");

        if (foodList.Length > 0)
        {
            //List<Vector2> foodsBehindSnake = new List<Vector2>();
            foreach(GameObject food in foodList)
            {
                //If angle required to turn towards food is greater than 90, food will be considered as behind snake
                float angleToFood = Mathf.Atan2(food.transform.position.y - this.transform.position.y, food.transform.position.x - this.transform.position.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                Debug.Log(angleToFood);
                if (angleToFood <=90f)
                {
                    Debug.Log("FOOD AT" + food.transform.position + " IS BEHIND SNAKE");
                    food.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.magenta;
                }
                
            }
        }

        yield return null;
    }
```

[here is a rough sketch of what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odhdC.png)

Comment: `if (0 < Vector3.Dot(previousSnakeHeadPosition - currentSnakeHeadPosition, foodPosition - currentSnakeHeadPosition)) { /* food is behind snake */ }`

Comment: By the way, it is very good that you included in the question why you wanted to find the angle, that it was really about trying to find if it is behind the snake or not. This helped avoid an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359), and more questions would benefit from that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Vector3.Dot()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Dot.html) for that. Remember, that it operates on *directions*, not *positions* - so you probably want to compare `transform.forward` of snake head with a difference of food and head position (e.x., direction from head to food).